# How to get the probability percentage of a model.predict() when clustering documents

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

```
text = "Some random text string that I want to cluster"
Y = vectorizer.transform([text])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)
```

the above passes through a value which is a string and then it it returns the cluster group it thinks it belongs in (one of three).

How can I find out what the percentage of its prediction accuracy is. ie. this particular text is 90% consistent with group 1, the next text might be 45% consistent with group 2 but it will still go into group 2 none the less. I want to be able to catch items with a low accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all, usually.

Even some (few) clusterers work with some probability inside, and may have a `predict_proba` function to get these values, these values rather capture a relative responsibility than an accuracy.

Comment: Hmm bummer. Is the distance of a data point to a centroid not a measurement of it's  probability to be in that cluster? ie. Closer to the centroid the more likely they are similar documents?

Comment: Well, it's not a probability. And in k-means there can be a far point that nevertheless clearly belongs to the cluster, and a much closer point that even is in a different cluster.

Comment: Nothing is preventing you from implementing such a logic yourself, though. For example Silhouette values work like that, have a look!